# On Checkout: what is in $parent.item_id? Not the product ID, not the database ID for the product... What else?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

If you try to get `item_id` in default.html (`module-checkout/web/templates/summary/item/details.html`), you don't get the products ID, you get something very different.

What is this ID and how can I turn this ID into a valid product ID? It has to be linked to the product anyhow, but how?

Looks like it is the quote's ID. Now I do need to get the Products ID based on this ID. How could I possibly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it is probably the Quote Item ID. You could validate this by checking if the item id matches the `item_id` column in the `quote_item` table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you specify your idea a little more, since I'm working on this matter for 5h straight now and I can't find any solution @_@. EDIT: I see the table quote_item in the database, and the item_ids are the correct ones. How can I get the product ID based on the item_id? Any ideas?